# Batch/VB Script to set of System Beep

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, system, beep

I'm wondering, with batch, vbs or any other built in windows languages, can I make the system beep (like the one when you press a key at startup) go off? I'm not sure if this is possible, but any help would be awesome!

Comment: Computers now often don't come with a 'speaker' or transducer as a cost cutting measure, so `control G` doesn't make any sound on such a PC.

Comment: rundll32 kernel32,Beep (to beep from speaker) rundll32 user32,MessageBeep (to do default beep sound - usually from sound card).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very easy using `ctrl+G` (which comes up as `^G` in cmd).

Simply Type:

```
Echo ^G
Echo ^G >> beep.txt
Type beep.txt
```

This can only be used in CMD, unless you redirect the output to a text file (As demonstrated above), where you can then copy it into your batch file or `type` the file when you want to beep.

Remember in the above code `^G` is achieved by key pressing `Ctrl` + `g`.

Mona

Comment: Cool! Thanks. Is there any way to make the sound a little  bit longer?

Comment: You can add more control G characters in a row on the same line to make it more obvious.

Comment: ^G can be generated by holding "Alt", then typing "7" on the right hand side of your keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

For VBScript:

```
WScript.StdOut.Write Chr(7)
```

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell this should work:

```
[char]0x7
```

Another option, as @Joey pointed out, is the [`Beep()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.beep%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
[Console]::Beep()
[Console]::Beep(500, 300)
```

Comment: In PowerShell you can just use `[Console]::Beep` and even change frequency and duration.

Answer (score 0):

For Vista and later you can use `forfiles` (code sample to use inside a batch file)

```
forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo 0x07"
```

Comment: @Monacraft, how does it not work? it works for me. Now i'm in a xp machine and using the forfiles from resource kit, pc beeps. I have used the same/similar code in other cases and works. Character 0x07 is the same that Control+G.

Comment: I have tried this on Windows 7 with the resource kit and it produces this error: `ERROR: Files of type "C:\beep.bat" not found.`

Comment: Note this works if you replace `"%~f0"` with `"%~nx0"`. I'll edit your answer.

Comment: @Monacraft, my fault. I have lost the count of the times i have written the `%~fx` construct in the last hour, and i typed it automatically. Also included the path reference to the directory of the batch file to avoid further problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can type

```
echo ^G
```

The ^G can be generated by holding "Alt", then typing "7" on the right hand side of your keyboard. Then press enter to hear the beep sound.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")    
oShell.Run "%comspec% /c echo " & Chr(7),0,false   
Set oShell = nothing
```